# C++ Copy String into Char String Array

Tags: c++

below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string data;

    data = "hello world";

    char string[] = new char [data.length()+1];;
strcpy(string, data.c_str());


}
```

I got an error..

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:14:46: error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘string’
```

What should i do as I want copy the content of string data into char string[]

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's not the problem this time, but avoid using (even namespaced) standard type names as variable names. I for one always have to do a double take.

Comment: Once you got the string declared correctly, you should probably use `memcpy()` as the length of the string is known unless the string to be copy may contain null characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to the following:

```
char* string = new char[data.size()+1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `char *string`, not `char string[]`.

The `char string[]` means that you define an **array**, and size of the array should be evaluated from the initializer in compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get it to compile, you'd have to use a `char*` instead of a `char[]`. `char[]` in this case requires a constant size, and since `data` is not a compile-time constant, the size cannot be determined.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
string Name="Hello FILE!"
int TempNumOne=Name.size();
char Filename[100];
for (int a=0;a<=TempNumOne;a++)
    {
        Filename[a]=Name[a];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
char* string = new char[data.length()+1];
//  ^
```

**`strcpy` take two pointers as argument.** `char string[]` means you are declaring an array.

Here is the prototype of the function :

> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);